# Bind to a TemplatedParent's name in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a WPF Custom Control which will bind itself to it's templated parent's x:Name property.  The code which I believe should do this which was also generated by the Binding Maker in Visual Studio, is as follows:

```
Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay
```

But this produces no result.  I can replace the binding with any plain text and the desired behavior (the text overlays itself on the control when and only when the user has typed nothing into the control), but my goal here is to make this work as a sort of tooltip so the user knows what the field is supposed to be (as defined in the field's x:Name property).

Here's my full xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SuperTB">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SuperTextB}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SuperTextB}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsRequired}"></TextBlock>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsRequired}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the control's c#:

```
    public class SuperTextB : Control
{

    static SuperTextB()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SuperTextB), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SuperTextB)));

    }

    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(SuperTextB));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }


    private static DependencyProperty myNameProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("MyName", typeof(string), typeof(SuperTextB), new PropertyMetadata("Unicorns !", NameChanged));

    private static void NameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string MyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(myNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(myNameProperty, value); }
    }
    DependencyProperty isRequiredProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsRequired", typeof(bool), typeof(SuperTextB), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsReqChanged));

    private static void IsReqChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(isRequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(isRequiredProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, two way binding to the `Name` property seems like a bad idea to me in general as that attribute is used for scoping, referencing and binding.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll flip it off.  Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. You mention `x:Name` in the first part, but do not reference it at all in your control. Plus your control has a MyName property, which doesn't appear to be used in the XAML at all. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The x:Name property is being set on this class of custom control in my application.  My goal is binding the x:Name property to the VisualBrush's Textblock in the control so I can name one of these something like FirstName in xaml and then, before the user enters text, the control will say FirstName.  I have tried binding to the MyName property with no joy (it's currently hardcoded to unicorns so that I knew that it was set to something during debugging).  Hopefully this clarifies my question?

Comment: But in your full XAML you are binding to `IsRequired`. I assume you were just testing stuff out and posted the wrong thing. You meant `Name` or `MyName`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, it should've been `name`.  `MyName` was a DP that I set up that in the constructor I was setting equal to `Name`, but that didn't accomplish anything so I gave up and just didn't take it out when I posted here.